# strange behavior of image adding to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I try to display some images on canvas that should displayed on click event. And everything seems ok, but I found some bug, that I cannot fix for a long. Bug is that on the **first** page opening lamp image does not display. It can be reproduced by following steps:

1. Open [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sKymY/12/) in browser;
2. click to button image <- clear rectangle will be displayed
3. click again. <- rectangle will be disappeared
4. click again. <- rectangle with image will be displayed

Why image doesnot display first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you have one (very common) error in your code. The method `.onload` expects to be assigned with a function reference. You are assigning it to the result (the return value) of the immediate function call `processButtonImages(i, delta, buttons[i], object)`. So as long as you are not returning a function reference from this function call (which you don't) this will not work as expected.

Comment: Hm, Actually I did not catch the meaning. So, what should I write to return reference?
Should it be something like this: `return processButtonImages;` at the end of `processButtonImages` function?

Comment: No actually you will have to reconsider your semantics at this point. Usually you could do this `buttons[i].onload = function() {processButtonImages(i, delta, buttons[i], object)};` but as you are assigning this in a loop it would still suffer from synchronization issues (due to the closure). You would need to either "loosen" the loop or create another (inner) closure to deal with the loop index

Comment: Yes, the problem was in this part of code. And after some additional debug I solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling and setting somethings in image onload event. So, at first it doesn't execute the whole thing correctly. Check this jsfiddle. I edited the code at the end, http://jsfiddle.net/sKymY/14/